# Stuck with old version of oauth2client when using Vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I've got a script that uses `gcloud` v0.7.1. As soon as I run it, I get the following error:

```
...
  File "/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/credentials.py", line 26, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import _get_application_default_credential_from_file
ImportError: cannot import name _get_application_default_credential_from_file
```

As far as I can tell, an older version (v1.2) of `oauth2client` is being used, even though I did a `pip install oauth2client==1.5.0`. This only happens on my Vagrant box (running CentOS 6.6, Python v 2.7.10, pip v7.1.2). When I'm outside of the Vagrant box I don't get this error.

`pip show oauth2client` (from within the Vagrant box) yields:

```
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: oauth2client
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: OAuth 2.0 client library
Home-page: http://github.com/google/oauth2client/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: six, pyasn1-modules, rsa, pyasn1, httplib2
```

However, I get back a different version number when I check it from Python using this command:
`python -c "import oauth2client; print oauth2client.__version__; print oauth2client.__file__"`:

```
1.2
/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/__init__.pyc
```

`import sys; print sys.path` yields:

```
['', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python27.zip', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/vagrant/venvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

How can I make sure that v1.5.0 is used?

Comment: Just to make sure, when you go to the vm and run `pip install --upgrade oauth2client` it does not fix it ? also here pip will believe it has the correct version ? how did you build the vm ? is it happening on a fresh install (in such case can you show Vagrantfile and provisioning part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a bunch of time on a similar problem tonight, so hope this helps: the [`google-api-python-client`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) library **used to bundle** the [`oauth2client`](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library until it was split out in a separate package. If you have `google-api-python-client<=1.2` installed, it may interfere with your installation of `oauth2client`, depending on the order in which you installed the libraries or your `PYTHONPATH`.

Python (with packages installed via `pip`) doesn't offer any guarantee that the folder you find in `site/dist-packages` is actually installed by the package of the same name.